# how to correctly copy requirements.txt for docker file

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, requirements.txt

This is how my current folder structure looks like:

[image]

I am present in the FinTechExplained_Python_Docker folder. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /src

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "main.py"]
```

However, when I run this command
`docker build --tag FinTechExplained_Python_Docker .`

I get this error

```
ERROR [3/5] COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt                    0.0s
------
 > [3/5] COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I also tried changing it to:

```
COPY str/requirements.txt requirements.txt:
```

but then I would still get the error that:

```
failed to compute cache key: "/src/requirements.txt" not found: not found
```

maybe the second COPY statement is also to be changed but not sure how

Comment: WORKDIR sets the working directory _inside_ the container, it doesn't change the root of the build context.

Comment: ah, I was trying to follow a tutorial here, https://medium.com/fintechexplained/running-python-in-docker-container-58cda726d574 hence the confusion @jonrsharpe but I still get the error even if I change it to ```COPY src/requirements.txt```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the source of your COPY statements relative to the build context, like this

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /src

COPY src/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ .

CMD [ "python", "main.py"]
```

Comment: ```failed to compute cache key: "/src/requirements.txt" not found: not found```

Comment: @x89 Do you get that error on the COPY of requirements.txt or on the `pip install`? And what OS is your host machine?

Comment: macOS. I get the error on the copy statement

Answer (score 2):

When building image from Dockerfile it searches file from directory where Dockerfile is located (`FinTechExplained_Python_Docker` in your case).

So basically requirements located at `FinTechExplained_Python_Docker/src/requirements.txt`, but docker searches them at `FinTechExplained_Python_Docker/requirements.txt`.

To fix this you have to change 5th line to:

```
COPY src/requirements.txt requirements.txt
```

Comment: Also I suggest you to read Docker docs, as @jonrsharpe said you don't understand  'WORKDIR': https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

Comment: Be aware that you also need to change the other COPY statement. Otherwise the CMD won't be able to find `main.py`

Comment: what do I need to change it to? @HansKilian

Comment: ah, I was trying to follow a tutorial here, https://medium.com/fintechexplained/running-python-in-docker-container-58cda726d574 hence the confusion. However, I still get the error with src/requirements.txt as well

Comment: @x89 Please see my answer where I've changed both COPY statements

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I think I got why you are having `failed to compute cache key...`.

When you are copying file in Dockerfile using COPY you have to pass ***Directory** where file should be saved* as second argument. 
Like `COPY LOCAL_PATH_TO_FILE SERVER_PATH_TO_DIRECTORY`

In your case:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /src

COPY src/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ .

CMD [ "python", "main.py"]
```